# How to bind <select> ng-model using ng-options inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

I have a `list` of tasks:

```
[{
    Titel: "Title1",
    Position: "9"
},{
    Titel: "Title2",
    Position: "1"
},{
    Titel: "Title3",
    Position: "5"
},{
    Titel: "Title4",
    Position: "7"
}]
```

I'm trying to create a `list` of `<select>`, where each is `list.lenght` long and has a selected value. The html snippet:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">  
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-authoringcontrols"><b>Title</b></td>
        <td class="ms-authoringcontrols"><b>Position</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="t in tasks">
        <td>
            <a href="TODO">{{t.Titel}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="t.Position" ng-options="t.Position as tasks.indexOf(i)+1 for i in tasks"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Output:
[image]

What it is missing, is the selected value (position) of each `<select>`. I Know the value is set by defining the ng-model and `ng-model="t.Position"` is wrong, but how can I set the `Position` value of each item to its related `select` element? The `<option>`'s of each `select` should be the length of the tasks and ordered from 1 to n.

Comment: You want to change the array order with the select's? or just the Position property?

Comment: I only want to set the Position property to the select boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, the [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) format you are looking for is `select as label for value in array`, where `select` is the value that will be assigned to the model.

In your case Position is string, so we need to convert `select` to string too so it matches the model:

```
ng-options="(tasks.indexOf(i)+1).toString() as tasks.indexOf(i)+1 for i in tasks"
            ^ model value                      ^ display
```

( `tasks.indexOf(i)+1+''` would work too)

```js
angular
  .module('Test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [{
          Titel: "Title1",
          Position: "9"
      },{
          Titel: "Title2",
          Position: "1"
      },{
          Titel: "Title3",
          Position: "3"
      },{
          Titel: "Title4",
          Position: "2"
      }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">  
      <tr>
          <td class="ms-authoringcontrols"><b>Title</b></td>
          <td class="ms-authoringcontrols"><b>Position</b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="t in tasks">
          <td>
              <a href="TODO">{{t.Titel}}</a>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select ng-model="t.Position" ng-options="(tasks.indexOf(i)+1).toString() as tasks.indexOf(i)+1 for i in tasks"></select>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <pre>{{tasks|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

> (If you run the snippet you will notice the first  is not
>   selected, that's because [1,2,3,4] doesn't contain 9.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the order of the item you need to keep track of the positions in a seperate array.

Here's an working example

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.tasks =  [{
    Titel: "Title1",
    Position: "9"
},{
    Titel: "Title2",
    Position: "1"
},{
    Titel: "Title3",
    Position: "5"
},{
    Titel: "Title4",
    Position: "7"
}];
$scope.positions = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">  
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-authoringcontrols"><b>Title</b></td>
        <td class="ms-authoringcontrols"><b>Position</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="t in tasks | orderBy: 'Position'">
        <td>
            <a href="TODO">{{t.Titel}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="t.Position" ng-options="i for i in positions"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the ordering of the tasks, Position is the value each `<select>` should have selected. However, your example would'd be ok if every select box had sorted values from 1 to n

Comment: Yes, but there must be a way to do it even without a second array, in your example `$scope.positions`.